# Does an aperiodic dynamical system have $n$-markers for any $n$?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, symbolic-dynamics

I was wondering if a certain lemma in an article by Downarowicz holds in a more general setting (see details below):

Let $(X,T)$ be a topological dynamical system. I.e. $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $T:X\rightarrow X$
is a continuous mapping.

Let us call an open subset $U\subset X$
an **$n$-marker** ($n\in\mathbb{N}$)
if

1. The sets $T^{-i}(U)$ $(1\leq i\leq n)$ are pairwise disjoint.
2. The sets $T^{-i}(U)$ $(1\leq i\leq m)$ cover $X$ for some $m\geq n$.

The system $(X,T)$ is said to have the **marker property** if
there exist open $n$-markers for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

My question is: Does all aperiodic ($T$ doesn't have periodic
points) dynamical systems have the marker property?

The above definition is a natural generalization of
a definition 2  in

Downarowicz, Tomasz. Minimal models for
noninvertible and not uniquely ergodic systems. Israel J. Math. 156
(2006), 93--110.

In particular based on lemma 1 in this article the
answer to the above question is yes if one assumes in addition that
the system has an aperiodic zero-dimensional factor.

It is easy to see that the answer is yes if $(X,T)$
has a non-trivial minimal (all orbits are dense) factor.

Comment: The definition of an $n$-marker isn't showing up for me; can you fix it?  If it's what I think it is, there should be many counterexamples (including an irrational rotation of the circle), but of course this is all contingent upon the definition.

Comment: I see -- that's a bit different than I thought it would be, so I retract my now-false claim about the irrational rotation.

Comment: Since I thought about a similar problem for a few months myself now, it should be noted (for future readers) that a positive answer was already found by Yonatan Gutman for the case of finite dimensional (invertible) systems. The paper can be found here http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.5248